# Database design for a simple social site

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, social-networking

I'm currently trying to design the database for a simple social site. I'm using MySQL for my database. Currently, I only have a users table. Basically, I want users to be able to add friends and be able to list their friends. I'm thinking of creating a friends table, something like:

```
friends table
user_id
friend_id
```

And whenever someone adds a friend, it will create an entry. I'm not exactly sure if I'm on the right direction. Another question, is there a way to retrieve all 2nd degree friends?(friends of friends) Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: create table which contains all the user information and has PK as user_id,  make frind_id as a FK for the friends table that too refer the user_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right path.

You can retrieve 2nd degree friends by joining the friends table to itself

```
select t2.friend_id
from friends t1 
     inner join friends t2 on t1.friend_id = t2.user_id
where t1.user_id = ...
```

One thing to consider is commutativity - if A is a friend of B, is B a friend of A ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a user table with all the user properties, and then another table to store the relationship between users.

The relationship table will contain two columns, each of them holding a user_id and in this table is where you will store the friendship between two users. (Otherwise you will only be able to have one friend per user).

In order to get different level of relationship you will need to make joins between both tables. (Depending on the RDMBS you use, you may have some shortcuts).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Sure. That would work fine.  What you've described is a self-referential many-to-many relationship.  Querying is fairly simple. Here's all the friends of $current_user:

```
select u.* from users as u 
  inner join friends as f on u.id = f.friend_id 
  where f.user_id = $current_user_id
```

On thing to consider is that this technically a directed graph.  So user A can be friends with user B but user B isn't necessarily friends with user A.

Answer (score 0):

I have a join table that stores friendships. There’s a column to store the ID of the user that requested the friendship, a column to store the ID of the user the request is sent to, a boolean column that’s stores whether the friendship has been accepted, and a timestamp column to store when the request was sent.